# AWS XRay with Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, aws-xray, quarkus-rest-client

I would like to trace downstream rest client calls using AWS Xray in Qurakus application.
Any idea how to enable aws xray tracing for Rest Client calls in Quarkus Application.

Comment: Please detail what you have tried so far, what resources you searched, etc.

Comment: I have a working Spring Boot Application where the downstream calls are using Feign Client which can be configured using HttpClientBuilder for XRAY tracing. Now I am trying to migrate the application to Quarkus. Since I am trying to use JAX-RS client in Quarkus, i am doing things with Request filter to start and end subsegment for tracing. Looking for a proper way to enable tracing for JAX-RS clients.

Answer (score 1):

XRay SDK and Daemon are in maintenance mode and would not add new feature support. So, it won't support JAX RS client instrumentation. Alternatively, you can use opentelemetry java instrumentation with Collector.
For more details please refer to:

- https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/java-sdk
- https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/jaxrs-client
- https://github.com/aws-observability